# How to fix syntax error in SWITCH function

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am attempting to fill a column labeled `type_match` depending on the content of two columns `2018_status` and `2019_status` in the `status_report` table.

All three columns are short text. I keep getting a 'syntax error'.

```
UPDATE status_report AS per  
SET per.type_match = 
Switch(
   per.2018_status = 'No application found', 'No application for 2018',
   per.2019_status = 'No application found', 'NA',
   per.2018_status = per.2019_status, 'Yes',
   True, 'No'
)
```

The documentation seems pretty straightforward and believe it's an MS Access issue where they tend to be very picky.

Comment: `True` is totally valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with Switch,  you only need to enclose in square brackets the column names that have numbers at the start:

```
UPDATE status_report AS per  
SET per.type_match = 
Switch(
   per.[2018_status] = 'No application found', 'No application for 2018',
   per.[2019_status] = 'No application found', 'NA',
   per.[2018_status] = per.[2019_status], 'Yes',
   True, 'No'
)
```

Comment: Wow that totally fixed it, I never thought that'd be an issue since I've never enclosed column names with square brackets

Comment: Column or table names starting with numbers, or containing spaces, or reserved words, all must be enclosed in square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `1=1` for the default:

```
UPDATE status_report AS per  
    SET per.type_match = Switch(per.2018_status = "No application found", "No application for 2018,
                                per.2019_status = "No application found", "NA",
                                per.2018_status = per.2019_status, "Yes",
                                1=1, "No"
                         );
```

MS Access also traditionally uses double quotes for strings, so I changed them as well.